# How can I research for specific data

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

This is my first time in the forum so if I made any mistakes please let me know.

So I have to do a research work for school and I am having a little bit of a problem finding a data set that meets all my requirements. This is for my database class. I have been looking the whole weekend and I have not been able to identify any valid source.

Still after all that I have been able to find nothing.

I was wondering if you could help me; perhaps there is a more flexible website to help me narrow the search; or a specific website with the information..

Here are all the requirements:

The data set must be from a legitimate source (e.g., the us gov, a state agency, a university).
The data set must measure something by date and by zip code. in essence, the data set can contain just 3 fields (date, zip code, measure).
The date range must be at least 10 years and span.
The level of granularity of the date must be at least by month, and in the format of YYYYMM or YYYYMMDD.
Zip code must cover all fifty (not 58) states. 
Anything except weather

Thanks a lot in advance for the help

Comment: Well it isn't exactly clear what you are looking for, but on here we mostly handle code and help diagnose problems with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [U.S. Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/econ/cbp/), there are several datasets that should match your need, although there is probably more information than the minimum you need: that is likely to be true in most real-world examples.